# How to convert a key and list of values to a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file which had key and values and some of the values were missing ,

```
key1 12 13 na
key1 na 11 11
key1 12 13 11
key2 11 12 10
key3 10 11 10
key3 na na na
```

I wanted to fill the missing values so I did (data is my rdd)

```
def fill_na(x):
    ldf = Df(list(x))
    df_with_na = ldf #df_with_na.toPandas()
    df_with_mode = df_with_na.fillna(df_with_na.mode().iloc[0])
    return_list = df_with_mode.values.tolist()
    return return_list

data1 = data.mapValues(fill_na).flatMapValues(f)
```

now data1 looks like:

```
data1.collect() 

(key1 ,[12 13 11])
(key1 ,[12 11 11])
(key1 ,[12 13 11])
(key2 ,[11 12 10])
(key3 ,[10 11 10])
(key3 ,[10 11 10])
```

now I want the above data1 to write into dataframe/table I tried

```
data1.toDF().toPandas()
```

but I am getting an error

```
TypeError: StringType can not accept object in type <type 'float'>
```

1)How do I write into a dataframe?
2)How do I convert key and list to a single tuple like below?

```
(key1 ,11,12,13)
```

so that I can directly write into dataframe?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you use a script without any pyspark specifics as well to read in that file into a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: This is a sample one ,my file is very big so I have to use pyspark

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spark programming guide on DataFrames and SQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-sources), try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

df = data.map(lambda (k, v): Row(k, v[0], v[1], v[2])).toDF()
```